# Increment server number in double loop with separator every 5 servers

Tags: python, loops, increment, separator

I need to have the following output

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
**********************
server6
server7
server8
server9
server10
**********************
server11
server12
server13
server14
server15
**********************
etc
```

And I have the following code

```
import random

s = 0
n = 0
nb = 0
nb0 = 20
nb1 = 5

var1 = "server"
var2 = "**********************"

for i in range(nb0):
    while nb < nb0:
        s = s + 1
        nb = nb + n
        for i in xrange(nb1):
            while n < nb1:
                n = n + 1
            print str(var1) + str(s)
        print var2
```

but the output is not correct and i am not able to find how I can continue to increment the server numberinside each loop until nb is reached.

```
server1
server1
server1
server1
server1
**********************
server2
server2
server2
server2
server2
**********************
server3
server3
server3
server3
server3
**********************
```

thanks for your help

Comment: here's a hint - use descriptive variable names instead of `n`, `s`, etc. It makes following the flow of your code and tracking down bugs **much** easier

Comment: why not just check if `server_number % 5 == 0`? then you'd know you're on multipe-of-five and can output the separator.

Comment: Hi MattDMo thanks for the info. I will use descriptive in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the modulo operator, here's a small demo:

```
numservers = 15 # put anything you want here
for i in range(1,numservers+1):
    print('server{}'.format(i))
    if i%5 == 0:
        print('*'*22)
```

Comment: thanks timgeb - simple and working as expected. you are the one :)

Comment: thanks again this one is very good as well and working as expected